# Let $n$ be an odd nine digit number divisible by $375$. How many $n$ exist such that the second to second-last digit are in an increasing order.

Tags: combinatorics

So if $n=\overline {a_1a_2a_3a_4...a_9}$

$a_2\le a_3\le a_4\le a_5\le...\le a8$

$n=2k+1$

$n=375q$

I'm completely stumped. There's so many cases to look at. I don't know how to incorporate the criteria of being divisible by $375$ with the criteria of the increasing order of the  middle digits. I can find either of them, but I don't know how to combine them?

Comment: 375=3*5^3 so you need digit sum divisible by 3 and also last four digits divisible by 125.

Comment: Is the latter the criteria for divisibility by 125?

Comment: John: Not quite. I should have said only the last 3 digits. Note that 1000=125*8 so only the last three digits are involved for divisibility by 125.

Comment: Ugh, I'm trying to solve it but I just don't get the right solution. So many cases to look at.

Comment: The number of cases is very small: If an odd number is divisible by $125$, it ends in $125$, $375$, $625$, or $875$.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but following on that, how do I decide the ways I can arrange the digits before $125$ and $375$?

Comment: I suspect the problem has not been described correctly. We are left with $125$ at the end or $375$. Neither works, since we can't avoid bigger digits to the left of the $1$ or the $3$.

Comment: It's not a strictly increasing order.

Comment: Well, for example the $125$ forces the second to sixth to be all $0$'s, or $00001$,  and so on up to $11111$. Now apply the divisibility by $3$ condition in each case to decide on the first digit. The other one is a bit more messy.

Comment: John Doe -- I just added a better explanation of how to finish the count to my answer below. I wound up with 186 such $n$

Comment: That is indeed the correct answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final three digits must form a number divisible by 125, and with the added requirement that for such a number $a,b,c$ we need $a \le b$ (the $c$ being the units digit of our number, so not affected) there are only the ending three digits 000, 125, 250, 375. The other multiples 500, 625, 750,875 all break the nondecreasing digit rule. Oops, yuu also need odd numbers, so only 125 and 375 qualify for endings.

For each of these it should then be relatively easy to find how many ways to pad it out to a nondecreasing sequence with sum 0 mod 3. For example with last digits 375 we need a decreasing sequence of length 6 all at least 3, and we have a final leading digit which has no requirement re. decreasing with the other digits.

We're in luck in a sense, since if the number is say hvwxyz375 then the digit sum without the h determines the high digit h mod 3, and also h cannot be 0 in a 9 digit number, so there are 3 choices each for the digit h, once it is known mod 3. For hvwxyz375 we can fill out the subsequence vwxyz using any digits from 0,1,2,3. The nondecreasing requirement then means we have for this subsequence say a 0,s, then b 1's, then c 2's, then d 3's where each of a,b,c,d is arbitrary nonnegative and a+b+c+d=5. The number of solutions to that is, using stars and bars, $\binom{5+3}{3}=56.$ Multiplying that by 3 for the choice of h then gives 168 values of $n$ ending with 375. A similar analysis for strings ending 125 gives another 18 values of $n$ So (if this is right) the total number of $n$ is $168+18=186.$

Comment: The number has to be odd as well. How do you calculate the amount of decreasing sequences? Additionally, the first digit doesn't have to be in decreasing order.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, just fixed my answer taking odd integers into account. There are counting formulas for nondecreasing sequences, I think looking up "stars and bars" gives some ways to do it.

Comment: I don't think stars and bars deal with this specific kind of questions.

Comment: One has to define the difference set. For example the nondecreasing sequence $2,5,5,6,8,9$ gives the internal difference sequence $(3,0,1,2,1)$ whose sum is 7, agreeing with $9-2.$